# Generalizing interval graphs to higher dimensions

Tags: graph-theory

Not every graph is an interval graph, and that makes the notion of `interval graph` non-trivial. I was wondering whether the following generalization of interval graphs to higher dimension is indeed non-trivial.

> A **$d$-geometric graph** is the intersection graph of a family of balls (open or closed) in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I observer the following:

- a $1$-geometric graph is simply an interval graph
- any $d$-geometric graph is an *intersection graph* (but that alone doesn't make it a non-trivial notion yet)
- a *unit disk graph* is a $2$-geometric graph
- a $d$-geometric graph is $d'$-geometric for every $d'\ge d$ as well
- *random geometric graphs* which are formed in $\mathbb{R}^d$ are $d$-geometric

Since random geometric graphs may be formed in any metric space in fact, I guess this definition may be extended to any metric space as well.

Is it true that there exist graphs which are not $d$-geometric for any $d$? Is it true that there exist graphs which are not geometric with respect to the general definition using a general metric space?